# How can I have my iOS app receive a push notification when a new record is created in mySQL DB?

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, push-notification

How can I have my iOS app receive a push notification when a new record is created in my mySQL DB?

I understand something similar to this can be accomplished using SQL Triggers but I cannot find anything related to how this can be implemented into a Swift iOS app and have it receive push notifications.

Comment: MySQL does not support this native PostgreSQL on the other hand has native push notifications. [listen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html) / [notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) .. So you would need to in your application if where is new data meaning you have to poll and push.

Comment: What would you recommend is the best way to have push notifications based on table updates work? Do you know how this could be written in swift

Comment: i assume your Iphone OS app does not connect directy to a MySQL server? i would suggest using a Node.js where you can do websocket broadcasting to other connected clients when a client updates a record ..

Comment: Found a even better example as swift is also used [here](https://medium.com/@spiromifsud/realtime-updates-in-ios-swift-4-using-socket-io-with-mysql-and-node-js-de9ae771529)

Comment: Why would your iOS app send a push notification? Wouldn't the server hosting the database send the notification?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake I fixed it. Any recommendations as to how this can be done?

Comment: @rmaddy would it be possible for the app to connect to the db with JSON and reload every few minutes and send a local notification if any changes occur?